# JSON object does not want to initialize

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I am trying to create a JSON object using some values I take from a form. For some reson the code isn't working. I triple checked all the names f the inputs so you can assume they are correct. I did isolate the problem to the line where I instantiate my JSON object:

```
    function createJSON()
    {
        if (document.forms["formIn"]["gender"][0].checked == true)
        {
            var g= "male";
        }
        else if (document.forms["formIn"]["gender"][1].checked == true)
        {
            var g= "male";
        }
        var jsonobj={"name":document.forms["formIn"]["name"].value, "surname":document.forms["formIn"]["surname"].value, "email":document.forms["formIn"]["email"], "dob":document.forms["formIn"]["dob"].value, "password":document.forms["formIn"]["password"].value, "cpassword":document.forms["formIn"]["confirm_password"].value, "gender":g}
        var jsonstr=JSON.stringify(jsonobj);
        alert(jsonstr);
        var newjobj=JSON.parse(jsonstr);
        alert(newjobj.email);
    }
```

Thanks for everyones help. I just didn't have a .value after my email. Cleared alot of other stupid mistakes aswell, but still my second alert only says [object] [object].

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console? If you isolated it down to one line, why did you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: could you post your html code?

Comment: any reason why not matter what gender you select... you are always male? ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure which part isn't working?  stringify and alerting the string?  or parsing and alerting the email?  What exactly isn't working as you expected?

Comment: I'm curious if hoisting is at fault here... Isn't it bad practice to have `var`s scattered throughout a function like this?

Comment: The scope of `var g` is limited to those if statements. `g` will be undefined when you construct your `jsonobj`

Comment: @Shmiddty: not quite. var will scope g to the function, not the if statement. However, if it fails both of the if statements, `g` will be undefined

Comment: @Shmiddty: just to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Smswx/

Comment: @Matt Ball: jut for incase. I have firebug but I don't think I'm using it right cause it wont give me any errors. I just cut out code and put a normal alert in to check what workedand what didn't. I can tell you that except for gender the first alert works fine in firefox the second alert only says [object] [object] and it doesn't work at all in the other browsers

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
function createJSON()
{
    var g = "unknown",
        jsonobj,
        jsonstr,
        newjobj;

    if (document.forms["formIn"]["gender"][0].checked == true)
    {
        g = "male";
    }
    else if (document.forms["formIn"]["gender"][1].checked == true)
    {
        g = "female";
    }
    jsonobj={"name":document.forms["formIn"]["name"].value, "surname":document.forms["formIn"]["surname"].value, "email":document.forms["formIn"]["email"], "dob":document.forms["formIn"]["dob"].value, "password":document.forms["formIn"]["password"].value, "cpassword":document.forms["formIn"]["confirm_password"].value, "gender":g}
    jsonstr=JSON.stringify(jsonobj);
    alert(jsonstr);
    newjobj=JSON.parse(jsonstr);
    alert(newjobj.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` at the end of where you instantiate your JSON object. Everything else seems to be okay though.

Comment: Semicolons are usually optional in JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm that's true... I would also like to see the error message he gets in the console as Matt Ball pointed out so if the OP could post that, it'd be a lot more helpful.